# Computing $\textrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}_m , \mathbb{Z}_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

If we have a pair of Abelian groups $G$ and $H$, I have been taught to compute the corresponding $\textrm{Ext}(G,H)$ groups in the following manner:

We find a *free resolution* of $G$; *i.e.* a couple of free Abelian groups $F_0$ and $F_1$ and corresponding homomorphisms $f_0$ and $f_1$ so that:

$$
0 \to F_1 \stackrel{f_1}\to F_0 \stackrel{f_0}\to G \to 0
$$

is a short exact sequence.

We then dualise with respect to $H$, to get the dual sequence:

$$
0 \to \textrm{Hom}(G,H) \stackrel{f_0^*}\to \textrm{Hom}(F_0,H) \stackrel{f_1^*}\to \textrm{Hom}(F_1,H) \to 0,
$$

where $f_0^*$ and $f_1^*$ represent the naturally induced dual maps.

The corresponding Ext groups are then defined as:

$$
\textrm{Ext}^0(G,H) := \textrm{Ker}(f_1^*)
$$

and

$$
\textrm{Ext}^1(G,H) := \textrm{Coker}(f_1^*).
$$

An example: We compute $\textrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z})$:

We note that:

$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\cdot p}\to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{1 \mapsto 1}\to \mathbb{Z}_p \to 0
$$

is a free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. We then dualise with respect to $\mathbb{Z}$ to obtain:

$$
0 \to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z}) \to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}) \stackrel{\cdot p^*}\to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}) \to 0,
$$

which, noting that $\cdot p^* = \cdot p$, reduces to:

$$
0 \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\cdot p}\to \mathbb{Z} \to 0.
$$

Hence:

$$
\textrm{Ext}^0(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z}) := \textrm{Ker}(\cdot p) = 0
$$

and

$$
\textrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z}) := \textrm{Coker}(\cdot p) = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}.
$$

But now to the point: I want to compute $\textrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}_n)$.

For the sake of simplicity, let us first compute $\textrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z}_q)$ for $p$ and $q$ distinct primes.

A free resolution for $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is given, as above, by:

$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\cdot p}\to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{1 \mapsto 1}\to \mathbb{Z}_p \to 0
$$

Dualising with respect to $\mathbb{Z}_q$ gives us:

$$
0 \to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z}_q) \to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_q) \stackrel{\cdot p^*}\to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_q) \to 0,
$$

which necessarily must reduce to:

$$
0 \to 0 \to 0 \stackrel{0}\to 0 \to 0,
$$

so that:

$$
\textrm{Ext}^0(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z}_q) := \textrm{Ker}(0) = 0
$$

and

$$
\textrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z}_q) := \textrm{Coker}(0) = 0.
$$

Now for the more general $\textrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}_n)$. We have a free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ given by:

$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\cdot m}\to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{1 \mapsto 1}\to \mathbb{Z}_m \to 0.
$$

Dualising with respect to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ yields:

$$
0 \to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}_n) \to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_n) \stackrel{\cdot m^*}\to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_n) \to 0,
$$

which reduces to:

$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z}_d \to 0 \stackrel{0}\to 0 \to 0,
$$

where $d := \textrm{gcd}(m,n)$.

Hence, we again get trivial Ext groups.

Now I know that the answer should be $\textrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}_n) = \mathbb{Z}_d$. This agrees with what we saw earlier, as $\gcd(p,q) = 1$.

I would much appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Many thanks.

**Addendum:** Grazie to Maxime Ramzi and Captain Lama for pointing out my mistake.

I will here complete the computation, for the benefit of posterity:

First the $p,q$ prime case:

A free resolution for $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is given, as above, by:

$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\cdot p}\to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{1 \mapsto 1}\to \mathbb{Z}_p \to 0
$$

Dualising with respect to $\mathbb{Z}_q$ gives us:

$$
0 \to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z}_q) \to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_q) \stackrel{\cdot p^*}\to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_q) \to 0,
$$

which becomes:

$$
0 \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z}_q \stackrel{\cdot p^*}\to \mathbb{Z}_q \to 0.
$$

Noting that $\cdot p^*: \mathbb{Z}_q \to \mathbb{Z}_q$ is a bijection, we get:

$$
\textrm{Ext}^0(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z}_q) := \textrm{Ker}(\cdot p^*) = 0
$$

and

$$
\textrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_p,\mathbb{Z}_q) := \textrm{Coker}(\cdot p^*) = 0.
$$

Now again for the more general $\textrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}_n)$. We have a free resolution of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ given by:

$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\cdot m}\to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{1 \mapsto 1}\to \mathbb{Z}_m \to 0.
$$

Dualising with respect to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ yields:

$$
0 \to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}_n) \to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_n) \stackrel{\cdot m^*}\to \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}_n) \to 0,
$$

which becomes:

$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z}_d \to \mathbb{Z}_n \stackrel{\cdot m^*}\to \mathbb{Z}_n \to 0,
$$

where $d := \textrm{gcd}(m,n)$.

Hence:

$$
\textrm{Ext}^0(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}_n) := \textrm{Ker}(\cdot m^*) = \mathbb{Z}_d
$$

and

$$
\textrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Z}_m,\mathbb{Z}_n) := \textrm{Coker}(\cdot m^*) = \mathbb{Z}_d.
$$

Right?

Comment: $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z/n)$ is not $0$ !

Comment: You should already have seen the warning sign when you found $0$ for $\operatorname{Ext}^0$ without using that $p\neq q$. Recall that $\operatorname{Ext}^0(G,H)$ is simply $\operatorname{Hom}(G,H)$.

Comment: "which necessarily must reduce to:" where does one start on the next line? It's completely wrong.

Comment: How are you getting $Hom(\mathbb{Z}_p, \mathbb{Z}_q)\cong \mathbb{Z}$? It should be $0$ for distinct primes $p,q$. ($Hom(\mathbb{Z}_p, \mathbb{Z}_q)\cong \mathbb{Z}_{gcd(p, q)} \cong \mathbb{Z}/1\mathbb{Z} \cong 0$)

Comment: @William You are completely right. I have corrected it now. Many thanks.

Comment: Your new computation seems right.

Comment: If I were to be a bit pedantic, I would have to say that once you identity $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/n)$ with $\mathbb{Z}/n$, then the map $.m^{*}$  (i.e."the compose me" map), needs to change to $.m$ (i.e. the mutliplication by $m$ map).